# Is it possible to see images on screen when shooting in continuous mode on a Nikon d5300?

Tags: nikon, rear-lcd, continuous-drive, nikon-d5300

When I take photos in [continuous mode](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-continuous-burst-mode-shooting-on-your-.html) (low mode) with my Nikon d5300, I see nothing on the screen while taking the photos, I only see the last taken photo when I stop shooting.

Is it possible to change the settings so that I can see the images on the screen while I shoot? 

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a function of the sequential writing of images to the memory card. The camera can't write one image after the other while also generating previews and displaying them. It is not controlled by a setting. You could probably do it with tethering (connecting the camera to a computer as you shoot) but that is very situation dependent.

Comment: Somehow the humble bridge camera I had before did show the images while I was shooting. Do you think this shortcoming is due to lack of processor capacity?

Comment: The humble bridge camera you had before probably wasn't 24 megapixels.

Comment: Indeed, but I thought a dSLR will have a much more powerful processor, too.

Comment: What SD card are you using? If you're pootling along with a class 4 you might find upgrading to a class 10 will help.